# Pixel-Perfect Collision With Texture Rotation

Tags: c#, xna

I have pixel-perfect collision down, but it only works with the texture rotated at 0 radians.  Here is my code for determining the pixel-perfect collision-

```
public static bool IntersectPixels(Texture2D sprite, Rectangle rectangleA, Color[] dataA, Texture2D sprite2, Rectangle rectangleB, Color[] dataB)
{
    sprite.GetData<Color>(dataA);
    sprite2.GetData<Color>(dataB);

    // Find the bounds of the rectangle intersection
    int top = Math.Max(rectangleA.Top, rectangleB.Top);
    int bottom = Math.Min(rectangleA.Bottom, rectangleB.Bottom);
    int left = Math.Max(rectangleA.Left, rectangleB.Left);
    int right = Math.Min(rectangleA.Right, rectangleB.Right);

    // Check every point within the intersection bounds
    for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
    {
        for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
        {
            // Get the color of both pixels at this point
            Color colorA = dataA[(x - rectangleA.Left) + (y - rectangleA.Top) * rectangleA.Width];
            Color colorB = dataB[(x - rectangleB.Left) + (y - rectangleB.Top) * rectangleB.Width];

            // If both pixels are not completely transparent,
            if (colorA.A != 0 && colorB.A != 0)
            {
                // then an intersection has been found
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // No intersection found
    return false;
}
```

I am having trouble with my collision when it is rotated.  How would I go about checking pixel collision with a rotated sprite?  Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You know you could draw the rotated texture to a `RenderTardet2D`, cast it to a `Texture2D` and then check against that with your existing method. Just know it's probably going to take away a ton of CPU for doing just that. I'd recommend a more efficient, different approach, but I don't know of any.

Comment: yes, thats problem once when you load texture it wont work if you rotate it or scale it.. check for matrix rotation... but, do you really neet pixel collision? it's cpu killer. better use rectange, circle or even polygon collsion.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you can exress all transformations with a matrix. That shouldn't be a problem with the helper methods. And if you use matrices, you can easily extend the program without having to change the collision code. Up to now, you can represent a translation with the position of the rectangle.

Let's assume object A has the transformation `transA` and object B has `transB`. Then you would iterate over all pixels of object A. If the pixel is not transparent, check which pixel of object B is at this very position and check if this pixel is transparent.

The tricky part is determining which pixel of object B is at a given position. This can be achieved with some matrix math.

You know the position in the space of object A. Firstly, we want to transform this local position to a global position on the screen. This is exactly what `transA` does. After that, we want to transform the global location to a local location in the space of object B. This is the inverse of `transB`. So, we have to transform the local position in A with the following matrix:

```
var fromAToB = transA * Matrix.Invert(transB);
//now iterate over each pixel of A
for(int x = 0; x < ...; ++x)
    for(int y = 0; y < ...; ++y)
    {
        //if the pixel is not transparent, then
        //calculate the position in B
        var posInA = new Vector2(x, y);
        var posInB = Vector2.Transform(posInA, fromAToB);
        //round posInB.X and posInB.Y to integer values
        //check if the position is within the range of texture B
        //check if the pixel is transparent
    }
```